# systemd User Timer Not Repeating

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I'm trying to run a systemd timer every minute as a user, but it isn't repeating after the initial trigger. The `ffmpeg-timelapse.timer` is configured with the `OnCalendar=minutely` to fire every minute, and the `ffmpeg-timelapse.target` is `WantedBy` the dependent services. This allows me to easily add/remove cameras from the timelapse configuration.

The issue I am encountering is when I start the `ffmpeg-timelapse.timer` unit it will schedule for the next minute, but it will not repeat. The same issue occurs if I start it with the `--now` argument.

`ffmpeg-timelapse.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every minute

[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely
Unit=ffmpeg-timelapse.target

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`ffmpeg-timelapse.target`

```
[Unit]
Description=Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

An example of the service file for a camera.

`ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Front Yard Timelapse Unit
Wants=ffmpeg-timelapse.timer

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -ac '. camera01.conf ; exec ffmpeg-timelapse.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=ffmpeg-timelapse.target
```

Enabling and starting the service schedules it for the next minute.

```
$ systemctl --user start ffmpeg-timelapse.timer 
$ systemctl --user list-timers 
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST PASSED UNIT                   ACTIVATES
Sat 2020-06-06 12:08:00 EDT  12s left n/a  n/a    ffmpeg-timelapse.timer ffmpeg-timelapse.target

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

However once it runs it does not fire a second time.

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers 
NEXT LEFT LAST                         PASSED      UNIT                   ACTIVATES
n/a  n/a  Sat 2020-06-06 12:08:42 EDT  1min 2s ago ffmpeg-timelapse.timer ffmpeg-timelapse.target

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

The user I am running this as has `linger` enabled.

```
$ loginctl show-user timelapse
UID=1000
GID=1000
Name=timelapse
Timestamp=Tue 2020-04-07 16:16:20 EDT
TimestampMonotonic=3291000946930
RuntimePath=/run/user/1000
Service=user@1000.service
Slice=user-1000.slice
Display=411982
State=active
Sessions=412092 411982 163185
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
Linger=yes
```

The status output looks correct to me.

```
$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse.target 
● ffmpeg-timelapse.target - Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Sat 2020-06-06 10:50:42 EDT; 1h 23min ago

$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse.timer 
● ffmpeg-timelapse.timer - Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every 5 minutes
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-06-06 12:13:25 EDT; 1min 1s ago

$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service 
● ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service - Front Yard Timelapse Unit
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-06-06 12:14:03 EDT; 35s ago
  Process: 4491 ExecStart=/bin/bash -ac '. camera01.conf ; exec ffmpeg-timelapse.sh'
 Main PID: 4491 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Below is the output of `journalctl -xe`

```
Jun 06 12:13:25 srv01 systemd[26482]: Started Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every minute.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jun 06 12:14:02 srv01 systemd[26482]: Started Front Yard Timelapse Unit.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the issue by looking at the `systemctl --user list-units --all ffmpeg*` output. The `ffmpeg-timelapse.target` was remaining loaded/active/active. Prior to the actual triggered event the `ffmpeg-timelapse.timer` have the `SUB` set to `waiting`.

```
UNIT                                LOAD   ACTIVE     SUB     JOB   DESCRIPTION                                             
ffmpeg-timelapse.target             loaded active     active  start Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
ffmpeg-timelapse.timer              loaded active     running       Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every minute
```

The fault lies in the `[Unit]` configuration of the `ffmpeg-timelapse.target`. I needed to add the `oneshot` configuration to it, otherwise the target unit remained active.

```
$ cat ffmpeg-timelapse.target
[Unit]
Type=oneshot
Description=Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

It's now repeating every minute as expected.

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers 
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED UNIT                   ACTIVATES
Sat 2020-06-06 12:58:00 EDT  13s left Sat 2020-06-06 12:57:42 EDT  3s ago ffmpeg-timelapse.timer ffmpeg-timelapse.target
```

This is what the units look like now.

```
UNIT                                  LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION                                             
ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service loaded inactive dead    Front Yard Timelapse Unit                               
ffmpeg-timelapse.target               loaded inactive dead    Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
ffmpeg-timelapse.timer                loaded active   waiting Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every minute
```

Status output for each one.

```
$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse.timer
● ffmpeg-timelapse.timer - Runs ffmpeg timelapse units every minute
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2020-06-06 12:59:30 EDT; 3min 43s ago

$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse.target 
● ffmpeg-timelapse.target - Triggers the individual timelapse units for each camera.
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-06-06 13:03:11 EDT; 6s ago

$ systemctl --user status ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service 
● ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service - Front Yard Timelapse Unit
   Loaded: loaded (/home/timelapse/.config/systemd/user/ffmpeg-timelapse01-front-yard.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-06-06 13:03:12 EDT; 8s ago
  Process: 9607 ExecStart=/bin/bash -ac '. camera01.conf ; exec ffmpeg-timelapse.sh'
 Main PID: 9607 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```